# Oracle SQL Trigger not getting created

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table passenger as shown below

```
Column       Null?        Type
------------------------------------
NAME          -          VARCHAR2(20)
ID          NOT NULL     NUMBER
ADDRESS       -          VARCHAR2(20)
CHARGES       -          NUMBER
```

I am learning triggers and I want to create a trigger that updates charges as charges + 100 before a new insert is done. Here is the trigger I created.

```sql
create or replace trigger flight
before insert on passenger
for each row
set new.charges = new.charges + 100;
/
```

However, I am getting the error `ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification`. I have tried replacing `new` with `:new`, adding begin & end blocks, but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalid syntax.

```
create or replace trigger flight
  before insert on passenger
  for each row
begin
  :new.charges := :new.charges + 100;
end;
/
```